# How to slice a json file?

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to slice a  json file to make it work properly: [JSON file](http://storage.googleapis.com/nacleanopenworldprodshards/ItemTemplates_cleanopenworldprodeu1.json)

Problem is the json file starts with `var Nations =`.

```
var Nations = {"Nations":[{"Name":"Neutral","CanBeUsedAsBotFiller":false,....
```

So I'm trying to get rid of it by slicing it off and saving it again:

```
import urllib.request

urlData = 'http://storage.googleapis.com/nacleanopenworldprodshards/Nations_cleanopenworldprodeu1.json'
webURL = urllib.request.urlopen(urlData)
data = webURL.read()
sliced_data = data[14:][:-1]

f = open(r'file.json', 'w')
f.write(str(sliced_data))
f.close()
```

But the saved file shows a `b'`

```
b'{"Nations":[{".....
```

How do I correctly get rid of it and have a json file that I can use in Python?

Comment: i guess you could remove the `var Nations = ` with sliced_data.replace('var Nations = ','')` and then you can use the `loads` function from the `json` module to convert it to python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is downloaded from the internet, therefore it's bytes. So you need to open the file as binary.

Note also you can make things shorter by using a context handler; and you can do both parts of the slice in one go:

```
sliced_data = data[14:-1]

with f as open(r'file.json', 'wb')
    f.write(str(sliced_data))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you decode as utf-8 it will convert the byte string to string.

```
f.write(sliced_data.decode('utf-8'))
```